# Java process in not killed after killing Spark Streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I wrote shell script to invoke spark-submit in yarn-client mode . When i run shell script using nohup , my spark job is submitted to yarn. After sometime , I use `yarn kill -applicationId <application_id> to kill spark application.`

Yarn UI shows the application has been killed.But when i execute `pstree -p | grep spark` (on linux machine)
It still shows

```
-sh(23177)---spark-submit(23178)---java(23179)-+-{java}+
```

i.e the java process is not killed. How do i make sure that java process also gets killed when i kill spark application?

Thanks